Is there anyway to add a note/alias to each IP in macOS Terminal New Remote Connection?
In macOS terminal.app, I can add remote SSH servers by IP addresses and ports. Can I add nicknames/aliases to each server so that I don't have to remember them (IP_Port->Corresponding Server) in my mind?

Have you set up an ~/.ssh/config alias for these and tested in your preferred local shell to see if that would help? Starting there opens up all sorts of fun and useful customizations.
